# How to run method synchronously from test project (no await)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm pretty new in using Task and the whole concept around it. Also I'm using **Net 4.0** (*VSTO development for Office 2007*)

I'd like to understand one thing I wrote in my app that is working in production but writing unit test for it ended up with using `Thread.Sleep` and checking if the task run to completion or not

### Background

The production code is pretty simple, it calls a service to check out an environment status (*PROD, STAGE, QA etc.*) it's done in a (`void`) method via `Task`, inside the Task body it sets a property that is updating UI (WPF) and it's working OK. note I'm not using **`Wait`** in that method. If the Task fails I continue with another one with the **`OnlyOnFaulted`**

### Problem

I try to unit test the method (void) so I'd like to run the method running **synchronously** and I'm failing there.
I read about [RunSynchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/dd321435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), also saw people using  task.**`Result`** (*which doesn't seems to be available for 4.0*), also tried `Scheduler.Current`, `AttachedToParent` etc.

I think the problem is my design, I guess I'm trying to call a method and saying "Hey, run synchronously" and it does but inside the method is another task that run async so no matter what it will always run async. Am I right? Is there a way how to test it without a loop in my test project and waiting for `RunToCompletion`?

Here is sample code I created for better understanding, I simplified it a bit. In real implementation there is a proper Test project in my solution, I'm mocking the service so it doesn't call the real one etc.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ImagineThisIsInTestProject();
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        var cls = new Program();
        cls.MyProdMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public string Status { get; private set; }

    public void MyProdMethod()
    {
        // I have more logic in my real method, serialization, handling errors
        Console.WriteLine("In my method");
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Setting status");
                        Status = "Yes I set it";
                        }, CancellationToken.None);
        Console.WriteLine("Finishing my method");
    }

    public static void ImagineThisIsInTestProject()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST started");
        var sut = new Program();
        var task = new Task(() => sut.MyProdMethod());
        task.RunSynchronously(); // I would assume this will wait until the task is finished?

        // here my assert if status is set
        Console.WriteLine($"Status is - {sut.Status}");
        Console.WriteLine("TEST finished");
    }
}
}
```

Output of the above is

```
TEST started
In my method
Finishing my method
Status is -
TEST finished
Setting status

Started
In my method
Finishing my method
Finished
Setting status
```

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using? Most (that are actively developed) have been updated to understand and support `async` tests.

Comment: Ah sorry Visual Studio, so I guess it's MS Test, for mocking Moq. And VS 2015 but targeting 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really test your method `public void MyProdMethod()` because:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Setting status");
                    Status = "Yes I set it";
                    }, CancellationToken.None);
```

is basically a fire and forget

There's no way to test this unless you wait for the task to finish.  I know you don't want to include the **Wait** but to test consider the following:

```
    public void MyProdMethod()
    {
        // I have more logic in my real method, serialization, handling errors
        Console.WriteLine("In my method");
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Setting status");
            Status = "Yes I set it";
        }, CancellationToken.None).Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Finishing my method");
    }
```

And then your test would be like the following:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var program = new Program();

        // Act
        program.MyProdMethod();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("Yes I set it", program.Status);
    }

}
```

If you take the **Wait** out the test will finish before the Task in the method has a chance to complete therefore resulting in a failed Assert.

Comment: Task @ODawg G, interesting I tried  it in the production code and got an exception "Task was cancelled" but the prod method is slightly different, it continues with a method that handles errors, like here - 
.ContinueWith(failedTask => HandleTaskError(failedTask), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
I'll try at home with the example code I sent here

Comment: Ok I got the reason why the Wait() doesn't work - I return the task to a variable which seems to be impossible. I I remove it (I don't need it to be honest I was probably testing something) then I can apply `Wai`t but this is blocking the code for run which in my case blocks the UI. I'll read more about `ContinueWith` which seems to be the way how to achieve what I want - Run async operation not blocking UI